# Centering text vertically, inside inline-block

Tags: html, css, alignment, center, vertical-alignment

I need to vertically align the text inside a div to the center. Pretty much the only limitation (that I can think of, right away) is that the container must be inline-block, so I can't use table-cells with vertical-align.

HTML

```
<div id='w'>
   <img src='http://www.science.unsw.edu.au/files/news/527C868C9284958A22F9E4D448BDDA12.JPG' />
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body {margin:0;background:#333}
#w {margin:10px;background:#fff;padding:10px;display:inline-block}
img {width:20%;float:left}
```

(Wouldn't let me post without code, if I linked to jsfiddle..)

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D5e9P/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the image float with vertical-align:

```
img{width:20%;vertical-align: middle;}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/D5e9P/1/

Comment: Well, that was embarrassingly simple! Thank you. PS: would you happen to know how to vertically center the text if it was inside another container? Also, I'll accept the answer right after the timelimit.

Comment: the vertical align is on the image not the span or parent

Comment: @Shomz,work great but why `vertical-align:middle` on img effected the text?

Comment: On inline elements, vertical-align controls where it aligns relative to other inline elements on the same line.  The default vertical-align value is "baseline".

Comment: Like @cimmanon said, and image is one rare element that is displayed inline and still behaves like, say, inline-block.

Comment: @user3339662 It should work the same way even if the text was in another container. Remember, it's the image that "dictates" aligning.

Comment: @Shomz Well yes, it works, but when there's more than one line of text, the text goes below the img, which is not what I want. You wouldn't happen to know how to make the text appear as a block when it's multilined? (I realize this is not the original question, but it's very related, so I'd rather not post a whole new one, if you know how to help)

Comment: The only way I know that works for pretty much everything is to have an absolutely positioned element. Give me a minute, I'll find you a tutorial.

Comment: This one seems nice: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
div#element-id {
    line-height: 20px; /* or the height of the div element */
    vertical-align: top;
}
```